# What does this Background check response mean?

Tags: job-offer, background-check, employer

I have just received the following:

> As of now we have cleared all of your references and it looks like your education and employment and employment at Sick Kids have been completed by our vendor as well.  I am just waiting on confirmation from our corporate security to ensure that they clear all of the information our vendor has received

This message came directly from the company I applied to and I am located in Canada

Could anyone help me understand what this means?

Comment: This message came directly from the company I applied to and I am located in Canada

Comment: @JimG. I'm not sure why you are being so dismissive of the need for location. The answer *could* be different depending on where in the world you are. Certainly there are terms here which mean nothing to me as a Brit.

Answer (score 10):

Doesn't sound like anything bad, the background agency have completed their checks, sounds like the employer's security team have final review/ sign off so they're just waiting for that to complete.  I assume they're telling you this as nothing came up in the report, and they are just waiting for the stamp of approval.